# Validating a form with unobtrusive JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom, unobtrusive-javascript

I am helping a friend study for her exam. A question was to create unobtrusive javascript to validate the forms in this HTML code. It seems like the if statement is never entered in this current code. What am I doing wrong? Thanks for the help.

Here is the git for the code: https://github.com/Nirakander/Validate-form

Comment: Please put relevant code into the question, thanks. Also, what is "unobtrusive JavaScript"?

Answer (score 3):

Use `if(current.value == "")` (no space between quotes, two equal sign - I am not sure if empty value is everywhere empty string or undefined).

Since the input value (if provided) is string and anything but empty string is true, it could be also handy to use `if(!current.value)`.

It is also worth to consider [HTML5 form validation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/Data_form_validation).

To your comment: the span-element is "removed" because your form is sent and the page reloads. To prevent it, place `e.preventDefault()` in the catch, where `e` is event parameter to the handler function. I also propose to use `innerText` (replace old error message) instead of `appendChild` (add new error message). In code:

```
function validateForm(e) { // event parameter
  try {
    ...
  }
  catch(oError){
    var errorRef = document.getElementById("errMsg");
    errorRef.innerText= oError; // innerText instead of appendChild
    e.preventDefault(); // this prevents form from sending
    // return false; // this is useful only in onsubmit content attribute; useless here
  }
}
```

I also proposed changes in your git repository: [fork](https://github.com/Nirakander/Validate-form/compare/master...janturon:patch-1)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. This is not working though. The problem seems to be after entering the catch statement. The text is appended to my span-element but is removed right away.

Comment: @KarinAndersson see the update in my answer. Thanks for the little swedish lesson :-)

Comment: Thank you very much for the help! This solved my problem. :-)